# Did Jewish scholars acknowledge/appreciate classical music?

Tags: music, modern-times

Were there any Jewish scholars who, based on Jewish scholarship, acknowledged classical music (be it baroque to neo-classical) in a positive light and/or ever make mention of specific composers or pieces of music?

Comment: Well, there's the Bach.

Comment: Isn't music part of the Sheva Chochmos?

Comment: I'm assuming Moses Mendelssohn appreciated the works of his grandson Felix.

Comment: Why the modern-times tag?

Comment: @YEZ classical music didn't exist until relatively recently.

Comment: @msh210 I guess so - I think of modern times as having started in maybe late 19th early 20th century, although it is a rather ill-defined term. Baroque lived in the 1600's.

Comment: @judahsimon what are the "Sheva Chochmos"?

Answer (score 4):

The last rebbe of Lubavitch said that putting ["*Haaderes v'haemuna*"](http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/english/173.html) to the tune of [*La Marseillaise*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise) spiritually elevates the French nation.

Source: [`http://chabad.org/297181`](http://chabad.org/297181) (page has a video that starts when the page loads)

Comment: But not everyone can do that

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, not everyone can put "_Haaderes v'haemuna_" to the tune of _La Marseillaise_? Not everyone can put a Jewish poem to a classical tune? Not everyone can spiritually elevate a nation? Not everyone who puts a Jewish poem to a classical tune spiritually elevates a nation? Or what?

Comment: Not everyone can elevate non-Jewish songs, all the more so elevating a nation in the process.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sound-the-great-shofar/16.htm indicates that putting that poem with that tune was the spontaneous work of a bunch of _chasidim_. And it's sung by a bunch of _chasidim_. So perhaps not everyone can elevate non-Jewish tunes or elevate a nation thereby, but I guess a bunch of _chasidim_ can.

Answer (score 0):

> [Salamone Rossi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salamone_Rossi) or Salomone Rossi (Hebrew: סלומונה רוסי or שלמה מן
>   האדומים‎) (Salamon, Schlomo; de' Rossi) (ca. 1570 – 1630) was an
>   Italian Jewish violinist and composer. He was a transitional figure
>   between the late Italian Renaissance period and early Baroque.

I'm unaware of how many shuls, currently, sing works by Rossi, now, as many of his Cantorial works are choral, and, unfortunately, there aren't too many shuls with choirs in the U.S.

Your question doesn't clarify the type of "Jewish scholars" you are seeking. FWIW, The Belz School of Jewish Music, affiliated with Yeshiva University, includes a number of works by Rossi in its cantorial training. I think that considering that among the faculty are notable and knowledgable cantors such as Cantors Sherwood Goffin and Malovani, they would qualify as having both musical as well as Judaic scholarship in this area - enough to understand why Rossi was a significant composer.

As for what's considered "classical" music - since @DoubleAA mentioned "The Bach", would Shlomo Carl **Bach** ;-) qualify? As controversial as he was, he was also very much appreciated, as well, and proof is readily audible in shuls and weddings. (Without him, what would the trumpets play after the glass is broken?)

Comment: I've heard that Canadian shuls still use choirs.

Comment: I'm not sure if Carlebach was trained/taught music. He couldn't read music. I would imagine this would hinder his appreciation for classical music

Comment: @Scimonster, [the BAYT](http://www.bayt.ca/) does, but seldom.